# Not sure why batch file isn't moving my PDF files

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
SET JOBNO=1008645
IF EXIST "X:\someArea\someFile.pdf" MOVE /Y "X:\someArea\someFile.pdf" 
"Y:\newArea\%JOBNO%\letter\"
```

I'm making some pdfs through my batch file and after they're created they aren't being moved properly like they should be.

I'm checking to see that if they exist, they should be moved to a new path area that contains my pathfile concatenated with the job number variable I set at the beginning.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should create `Y:\newArea\%JOBNO%\letter\` first.

Comment: There is no line-break between source and destination paths of the `move` command in your true code, is it? Anyway, run the batch file by typing its path and name into a command prompt window rather than by double-clicking, so you can see the output, including error messages...

Answer (score 0):

Change your structure to something a little more like this:

```bat
SET "JOBNUM=1008645"

SET "SRCPDF=X:\someArea\someFile.pdf"
SET "DSTDIR=Y:\newArea\%JOBNUM%\letter"

IF EXIST "%SRCPDF%" (
    IF NOT EXIST "%DSTDIR%\" MD "%DSTDIR%"
    MOVE /Y "%SRCPDF%" "%DSTDIR%"
)
```